# Trying to get 2 field to match data in a second sheet and return a value

Tags: excel-formula

Im trying to get the following working in excel and i just cant seem to do it.
I have 2 sheets, one with data in (Sheet 2), one where ive created a questions box with a response field (Sheet 1).
So in the data sheet there are columns A, B and C.
On the questions box (Sheet 1) i need to know if a figure put into A and a figure put into B, both match the data in columns A and B in Sheet 2 if they do i want to return the figure which corresponds in column C in sheet 3 to column C in sheet 1.

Ive assumed i need to use an IF AND formula and have tried the following in various different ways, but all it gives me back each time is 0.

`=IF(AND(A1=Sheet3!A:A,B1=Sheet3!B:B),Sheet3!C:C,0)`

Im at the end of my tether with this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it needs to be an array formula, have you tried confirming this with Ctrl + Shift + Enter from in the formula bar?

Comment: Hi Richard,
 Yes but all that seems to come back is the 0

Comment: Sorry, it's the `AND()` not treating the array appropriately and taking either the first or last in the range (can't remember which one)... Try nesting two `IF()`'s: `=IF(A1=Sheet3!A:A,IF(B1=Sheet3!B:B,Sheet3!C:C,0),0)`

Comment: Also, with array formulas, you really should try to narrow the range down if at all possible, calculating for the entire column is asking it to do a lot of work, especially if you are never going to use more than 1000 rows.

Comment: I will give it a go now Richard
Theres over 20,000 records to search through currently.
its an old spreadsheet based company that im trying to bring a bit or automation to as such to make life easier.

Comment: Seems strange, if theres half a dozen or so records used for testing your equation works fine Richard, however if i then attach the formula to the full spreadsheet it is constantly giving a 0 back again, any ideas?

Comment: Apologies that I couldn't return to this yesterday, I had a flurry of bug fixes to work on. Please see my answer and let me know if it works (I haven't tried it, but it should be fine)

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy using an array formula (press `Ctrl` and `Shift` when you press `Enter`), then this formula should work fine:

I originally read it as you wanted to get the info from Sheet 3, so this would have worked:

<s>`=INDEX(Sheet3!B1:B6,MATCH(INDEX(Sheet2!C1:C6,MATCH(A1&B1,Sheet2!A1:A6&Sheet2!B1:B6,0),1),Sheet3!A1:A6,0),1)`</s>

But re-reading, I don't think that's the case, so this should do...

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C1:C6,MATCH(A1&B1,Sheet2!A1:A6&Sheet2!B1:B6,0),1)`

This is using:

`A1` as your first answer to compare values in `A1:A6` in `Sheet2`

`B1` as your first answer to compare values in `B1:B6` in `Sheet2`

Gets the corresponding value where both the above two match from `C1:C6` in `Sheet2`.

<s>Then, it looks for that value in `A1:A6` in `Sheet3` and returns the corresponding value from `B1:B6` in `Sheet3`</s>

Answer (score 0):

This is an array formula, apply this by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!C:C,SMALL(IF(A1=Sheet3!A:A,IF(B1=Sheet3!B:B,ROW(Sheet3!A:A)),1)),"No Match Found")`

This should work by building an array of the row numbers that have a match for both A and B then take the first match, `SMALL([array],1)`, by taking the first smallest number from the array and feeding that to `INDEX()`.

This formula can be adjusted to be dragged so that it returns multiple matches by changing small to `SMALL([array],ROW(1:1)` and dragging the formula down, though I would suggest changing "No Match Found" to "" so that you just have blank cells once you have displayed all of the matches.